# Displaying a Facebook Auth photoURL in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

I am using React and Firebase and receive the following when logged in

```
photoURL: https://graph.facebook.com/10157648190117379/picture
```

If I try to display this in JSX using:

```
<image src={this.props.user.photoURL} />
```

nothing renders.

I notice navigating directly to the link doesn't actually show an image, but prompts a download. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it won't work. Because there is a typo and there is no tag named `Image` in HTML.

To display an image, you have to use an `img` tag.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = { url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/10157648190117379/picture'}

  render() {
    return <img alt='Profile' src={this.state.url} />;
  }
}
export default App;
```

No Problem in the URL. Just make sure to use the correct tag.

Answer (score 1):

**I try this and it work**

```
import React from "react";
const TestCompOne = (props) => {
  console.log("[TEST COMP 1]");
  return (
    <div>
     <img src={"https://graph.facebook.com/10157648190117379/picture"} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestCompOne;
```